# The bubble sort, is sorting the year born in the linked list but it's not bringing the other elements in the struct with it when displayed to screen

Tags: c, sorting, struct, bubble-sort

The bubble sort, is sorting the year born in the linked list but it's not bringing the other elements in the struct with it when displayed to screen. it's just swapping the year born around in sorted order. How do I bring the rest of the information in the struct along with the year born being sorted. Thanks

```
typedef struct NodeT_
{
    int PPSNumber;
    char firstName[30];
    char secondName[30];
    int yearBorn;
    char email[40];
    int areasTravelFrom;
    int typeTicket;
    int tripsPerYear;
    int averageSpent;
    

    struct NodeT_* NEXT;
}node;

void DisplayList(struct node* top) {

     node* temp ;
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        printf("Nothing in list\n");
    }
    else
    {
        temp = top;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("======DisplayList=========\n");
            printf(" PPS Number:%d\n", temp->PPSNumber);
            printf(" First Name:%s\n", temp->firstName);
            printf(" Second Name:%s\n", temp->secondName);
            printf(" Year born: %d\n", temp->yearBorn);
            printf(" Email: %s\n", temp->email);
            
            //area travelled from
            printf("Area travelled from:\n");
            if (temp->areasTravelFrom == 1)
            {
                printf("Traveled from Galway city\n");
            }
            else if (temp->areasTravelFrom == 2)
            {
                printf("Traveled from Galway county\n");
            }
            else if (temp->areasTravelFrom == 3)
            {
                printf("Traveled from Connacht\n");
            }
            else if (temp->areasTravelFrom == 4)
            {
                printf("Traveled from other areas in Ireland\n");
            }
            else if (temp->areasTravelFrom == 5)
            {
                printf("Traveled from outside Ireland\n");
            }

            // type of tickets
            printf("Type of ticket purchased:\n");
            if (temp->typeTicket == 1)
            {
                printf("Normal Ticket\n");
            }
            else if (temp->typeTicket)
            {
                printf("Luxury ticket\n");
            }

            // trips to cinema
            printf("Trips made to the cinema per year:\n");
            if (temp->tripsPerYear == 1)
            {
                printf("Less than 3 times per year\n");
            }
            else if (temp->tripsPerYear == 2)
            {
                printf("Less than 5 times per year\n");
            }
            else if (temp->tripsPerYear == 3)
            {
                printf("more than 5 times per year\n");
            }

            // average spend on shop
            printf("average spend on cinema shop:\n");
            if (temp->averageSpent == 1) {

                printf("Nothing\n");
            }
            else if (temp->averageSpent == 2) {

                printf("Less than 5 euro\n");
            }
            else if (temp->averageSpent == 3) {

                printf("Less than 10 euro\n");
            }
            else if (temp->averageSpent == 4) {

                printf("More than 5 euro\n");
            }


            printf("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
            temp = temp->NEXT;






        }// while

    }//else


}// display list

void bubbleSort(struct node* start) {
    int swapped, i;
     node* ptr1;
     node* lptr = NULL;

    /* Checking for empty list */
    if (start == NULL)
        return;

    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1 = start;

        while (ptr1->NEXT != lptr)
        {
            if (ptr1->yearBorn > ptr1->NEXT->yearBorn)
            {
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->NEXT);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->NEXT;
        }
        lptr = ptr1;
    }while (swapped);


}// bubble

void swap( node* a, node* b) {

    int temp = a->yearBorn;
    a->yearBorn = b->yearBorn;
    b->yearBorn = temp;

}// swap
```

Answer (score 0):

your swap function should look like this:

```
void swap(node *a, node *b) {
    node temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

because when you want to swap 2 pointers, you have to swap what they pointing to, like in the code, we create the temp pointer point to target of a, and then set a point to target of b, and set b point to target of temp (it's a's target from the start)